# What is the meaning of the notation of function

Tags: functions, notation, linear-transformations

More specifically, what is meant by the function $T: \mathbf V \to \mathbf W$?
I saw it in the discussion of linear map in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right but could not understand this notation. 
Does it mean something like 'take an object $a \in V$ then process it into an object $b \in W$? Could somebody please explain in detail to me?

Comment: $T: V \to W$ means that $T$ is a function with domain $V$ and codomain $W$ :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29#Notation

Comment: This is a perfectly normal question.  I genuinely don't understand why it received 3 downvotes, and I'm further baffled that none of the three had the energy to let you know why they downvoted.  I'm apologizing to you on their behalf.  Please don't think negatively of this site because of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, when you write $T : V \to W$ in linear algebra to denote a linear transformation between vector spaces, this notation gives you three very important pieces of information.

1. It tells you the name of the map.  In this case, the name is $T$.  So when we talk about, for example, $T(v)$, where $v$ is a vector in the domain of the map, you know which map we are talking about.
2. It tells you the domain of the transformation $T$, i.e., the set of inputs.  In this case, the domain is the vector space $V$.
3. It tells you the codomain of linear transformation $T$, i.e., the set/space to which the outputs belong.  In this case, the codomain is the vector space $W$.

Note that the codomain is different in general than the range.  This is because the range of any map is actually by definition equal to the set of outputs.  But the codomain can be larger than this set.  The codomain is the structure where the range lives.  If the codomain *equals* the range (i.e., every element in the codomain has an element in the domain being mapped to it), then the transformation is said to be *onto*.

Comment: Is there occasions when we say _into_ ?

Comment: @Rescy_ In general, when you see the notation $T: V \to W$, you would read this out loud to yourself as "the transformation $T$ which maps the vector space $V$ *into* the vector space $W$".  The word "into" just means that $V$ is the domain and $W$ is the codomain.  If the map is *onto*, you would read the notation aloud exactly the same way, except replacing "into" with "onto".

Comment: @Rescy_ So basically saying "into" is the most general vocabulary with nothing special about it.  Every possible transformation/function/map sends the domain "into" the codomain.  It's the word "onto" that has special meaning.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @Rescy_ You're welcome! Thanks for choosing this site to seek help. :)

Answer (score 1):

It means at the most fundamental level that $T$ is a set of ordered pairs $(v, w)$ where $v$ is an element of $V$ and $w$ of $W$, which has the additional constraint that there is only one pair with any given $v$: ie. it is one-to-one. It can be more useful to think about it in the sense of $T$ being an action that you do to v in order to produce $w$, but in terms of set theory, that's what the notation represents.